# How to compile inside anonymous function in CoffeeScript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm creating Backbone plugin and suppose I have a CoffeeScript code as below.

```
((root, factory) ->
  if typeof exports is "object" and typeof require is "function"
    # CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require("backbone"))
  else if typeof define is "function" and define.amd
    # AMD
    define [
      "backbone"
    ], (Backbone) ->
      factory Backbone or root.Backbone
  else
    # Browser globals
    factory Backbone
) @, (Backbone) ->
  console.log Backbone # here will be main code.
```

Then I compile and the result is:

```
(function() {
  (function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof require === "function") {
      return module.exports = factory(require("backbone"));
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
      return define(["backbone"], function(Backbone) {
        return factory(Backbone || root.Backbone);
      }); 
    } else {
      return factory(Backbone);
    }   
  })(this, function(Backbone) {
    return console.log(Backbone);
  }); 

}).call(this);
```

However I'd like to divede as 2 CoffeeScript files (or any number of files), then concat both of them by grunt-contrib-coffee, but the compiled JS should be same result. Is it possible? Do  you have any ideas?

`a.coffee`:

```
((root, factory) ->
  if typeof exports is "object" and typeof require is "function"
    # CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require("backbone"))
  else if typeof define is "function" and define.amd
    # AMD
    define [
      "backbone"
    ], (Backbone) ->
      factory Backbone or root.Backbone
  else
    # Browser globals
    factory Backbone
) @, (Backbone) ->
```

`b.coffee`:

```
console.log Backbone
```

### Update

By Kursion's idea, I achieved somehow that I wanted to do, though it's a tricky ;P

`grunt indent` -> `grunt concat` -> `grunt coffee`

```
  grunt.initConfig
    indent:
      scripts:
        src: ['src/main.coffee']
        dest: 'tmp/'
        options:
          style: 'space'
          size: 2
          change: 1

    concat:
      sources:
        options:
          separator: ''
        src: [
          'src/entry.coffee'
          'tmp/main.coffee'
        ]   
        dest: 'tmp/example.coffee'

    coffee:
      compile:
        files:
          'lib/example.js': 'tmp/example.coffee'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be hard because of the indentation problems linked to CoffeeScript.

What you can do is a script that concat the two files but you will need to respect the indentation in the second file.

After the concatenation you can compile the CoffeeScript source.

**a.coffee**

```
((root, factory) ->
  if typeof exports is "object" and typeof require is "function"
    # CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require("backbone"))
  else if typeof define is "function" and define.amd
    # AMD
    define [
      "backbone"
    ], (Backbone) ->
      factory Backbone or root.Backbone
  else
    # Browser globals
    factory Backbone
) @, (Backbone) ->
```

**b.coffee**

```
    console.log Backbone # With indentation
```

---

Concatenation of both file in order to have: 
**glued.coffee**

```
((root, factory) ->
  if typeof exports is "object" and typeof require is "function"
    # CommonJS
    module.exports = factory(require("backbone"))
  else if typeof define is "function" and define.amd
    # AMD
    define [
      "backbone"
    ], (Backbone) ->
      factory Backbone or root.Backbone
  else
    # Browser globals
    factory Backbone
) @, (Backbone) ->
    console.log Backbone # With indentation
```

Then compile: `coffee --compile glued.coffee`

Comment: Thanks! it should be worked, but it's a bit weird way to care indentation from second file :(
wao, there is grunt indent plugin (https://github.com/stevenbenner/grunt-indent), so this should be also worked, grunt indent from second files -> grunt concat -> grunt coffee :P

Comment: Indentation in CoffeeScript is part of the syntax ;)